# Kotlin scope functions are actually java anonymous classes?

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm

I'm currently working on some old Java written Android project, but writing new parts in Kotlin which I'm not really familiar with. I need some way to unwrap nullable object(analogue of `if let unwrappedMyVar = myVar else {}` in Swift), to do this I use `myVar?.let {}` scope function which unwraps `myWar` and executes block in case it is not null. But now I'm actually curious how those scope functions are implemented in Kotlin, are the actually compiled to Java anonymous classes ? If so, then it can lead to the same problems that Java anonymous classes have. And it is quite easy to create the leak
Thank you !
Kind Regards,
Andre

Comment: They are not, the objects you are talking about doesn't exist on the bytecode generated. The function simply gets copied at the call site, effectively reducing all the performance overhead. Read more about them at [Inline Functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html)

Comment: By the way, in Kotlin you wouldn't talk of ‘unwrapping’ a variable in this context.  It's just that within the `let()`, the compiler knows that the value cannot be null.  (It expresses this in the type: if the original value were a nullable `String?`, the result would be a non-nullable `String`.)  This is called [smart-casting](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The scope functions like `let`, `apply`, `run`, or `also`, as well as many more functions in the Kotlin standard library, are [`inline` functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html), which means that the lambdas that you pass to them get inlined in their bodies, and the transformed bodies then get inlined at the call site.

With the scope functions, the resulting bytecode is mostly equivalent to what you would get with just declaring a variable and using it after an explicit `if`-null-check.